# React + Redux for a complex SaaS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm just starting with a React + Redux frontend for a complex SaaS we`re developing.

One thing I`m not sure of is how *store* (from redux) should work for a big application. The system we're developing has many tables, and a very complex data structure. If I would have all reducers putting data from every part of the application, it would be too much.

Can i enable/disable some reducers for certain parts of the application? Or should I have different stores that are composed of different reducers? Most of the examples I saw online were quite simple, so it was fine to have all data in the *store* at all times.

Another question: What would be a neat way of making the requests that I need for the page I`m trying to load? For example: suppose I have components A, B and C that require information about the tables "users", "movies" and "settings" respectively. In one page I have components A & B, and in the other one I have components B & C, is there any tool that help me get only data I need based on the "requirement" of certain components? Or is it done manually?

Again, I`m just starting to learn react+redux, sorry for the newbie questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic usage of redux is to have one store, although some may consider separate stores if the application can be split up into separate, unconnected parts.

The common practice is to *compose* reducers (as I think you have suggested); you can make this hierarchical, so a reducer may be composed of several others. Redux is pretty performant if split up this way.

I would think carefully about your state; keeping it normalized as possible is very important, and if you have large amounts of data, *preferring objects over arrays* will also help when accessing individual items.

If you can keep the state highly normalized, you can use *selectors* to derive view data when rendering; if you do this a libarray like *reselect* memoizes the functions for you improving performance again.

This is a good read:

http://www.thinkloop.com/article/extreme-decoupling-react-redux-selectors/

Comment: Thanks Mark!

I was suggesting something different I think. I think my way of making a store and its reducers might be very wrong. 

My application will have a RESTful api in PHP. Let's say that I need information about users, movies and songs. I would probably have a reducer for each one, right? And inside those I would have calls to my backend asking for the data they're looking for, so supposedly 3 requests on my server. Every time I change my state, I would call my reducers and they would trigger a server call? Regardless of where was the change? That sounds wrong for me.

Comment: You shouldn't (with all due respect) make the api calls from within the reducers - these should be pure functions without side effects. People usually get the data from within an action creator and dispatch another action (e.g data retrieved) on success. You may also consider middleware here. Great stuff on it here:https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-fetching-data-on-route-change (plus the whole course - it's free!)

Comment: Thank you so much!
That`s probably the part I'm missing from the redux concept.
This course seems very useful for me, thanks again.